# the semigroup generated by elementary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

This is from Artin's Algebra(2nd Edition) Ch.2 M.15. The question is:

---

"Determine the semigroup generated by the two real elementary matrices $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$, and prove that every element of $S$ can be expressed uniquely as a product of the two matrices."

---

**What I know so far**:
if $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right)=B^{b_{1}}A^{a_{1}}\cdots B^{b_{k}}A^{a_{k}}$, where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are positive integers, then

1. $a,b,c,d$ are all positive integers, and $\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(b,d)=1$, and
2. $a/c$ and $b/d$ can be expressed as continued fractions: $$\frac{a}{c}=\frac{1}{b_{1}+\frac{1}{a_{1}+\cdots\frac{1}{a_{k-1}+\frac{1}{b_{k}}}}},$$ $$\frac{b}{d}=\frac{1}{b_{1}+\frac{1}{a_{1}+\cdots\frac{1}{b_{k}+\frac{1}{a_{k}}}}}.$$

I have not come up with a way to prove the uniqueness. I also believe that there must be some better representation of $S$. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M=\pmatrix{r&s\\t&u}$ is a nonsingular matrix with nonnegative integer matrices, then
$AM=\pmatrix{r+t&s+u\\t&u}$
so the first row minus the second row of $AM$ is a nonnegative nonzero row vector.
Similarly taking the first row minus the second row of $BM$ gives a non-positive
row vector. Therefore in a product of $A$s and $B$s we can detect uniquely
 whether the
first matrix is $A$ or $B$. Cancelling that and repeating, then we can determine uniquely the entire sequence of $A$s and $B$s.